# Mass Upload to Windows Phone 8 Isolated Storage

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage

I am wondering if there is a way to upload a high number of files(*.txt)/images(*.jpg) to wp8 isolated storage?

Currentley i am working on a project inside a school wich will not give me the ability to download any extra SDKs.
We are running visual studio 2012 and in order for the project to work we will need to read from many *.txt files. The files have already been created so i dont want to have to recreate them in code

Also, is there a different method for uploading files to the isolated storage in the VS2012 phone emulator compared to the actual phone?

Answer (score 0):

You have Isolage Storage Explorer Tool, that is a command line tool to access phone/emulator internal storage.

Read here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh286408(v=vs.105).aspx